# How can I animate a pandas timeseries?

Tags: python, matplotlib, time-series, pandas

I have pandas timeseries with datetime column as index:

```
2010-09-20    1828.27
2010-09-21    1843.30
2010-09-22    1898.05
2010-09-23    1897.00
2010-09-24    1902.00
2010-09-27    1828.96
2010-09-28    1824.85
2010-09-29    1808.17
2010-09-30    1833.04
```

How do I animate this dataset using [simple](http://matplotlib.org/examples/animation/simple_anim.html) matplotlib example.

Comment: modify the `animate` function in that example to pull data from the pandas structures.